# Event binding to html server response

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble understanding how you would go about firing a particular function from an element which was rendered by a server response.

In the component's template I have something like a div (id="myDiv")

I make a request to a server, which returns HTML markup. So in my component, I would do something like 
`$('#myDiv').html(response);`

The problem with this is that I get a full page with HTML markup and every`<li>` item has an a tag: `<a href="javascript: myFunction();"`. Since all elements are already being passed in as plain html, how would I go about having a `(click)="myFunction"` event binding on each li item?

Edit: (and sorry for the format, as you can see Ive never really posted anything before)

I have a function

```
loadData(val){
 let url = 'http://www.something.com/some-endpoint?lg='+val;
 $.post(url,function(data)){
  $('#myDiv').html(data);
 }
}
```

The `data` response is long and complex, and somewhere in there, there's:

```
<li><a href="javascript: loadData(@id)"></a></li>
```

I cannot run the `loadData()` when the user clicks on the a tag, because angular won't fire the function.

I cannot add a `(click)="loadData()"`, since it's a response I'm getting from the server.

Comment: you want to trigger an `onClick` event on dynamically added `li` right ?

Comment: yes, basically I cannot manipulate the li in the template, since the response is already a full page, HTML markup. The li's are anchor tags with the `href="javascript: someFunction();"` syntax, so the function is not firing

Comment: Could you provide a code sample that recreates the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: how is this even related to angular?

Comment: because im working with angular?

Comment: that doesn't mean that your problem is related to it lol

Answer (score 0):

As you're adding those `li` dynamically, this should work

```
 $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
  //Do what ever you want on click event

});
```

Or

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
  //Do what ever you want on click event
});
```

Or you can add class to all those 'a' tags and try

```
$(document).on('click', 'NameOfClassAddedinATages', function(){
  //Do what ever you want on click event

});
```